# Getting the output as object instead of string

Tags: java, hibernate

In the following program I am getting the output as `Hibernate.UserDetails@224b4d61`

**How should i fix this?**

The following are the two programs I am using and I need to print the `username`

**HibernateTest:**

```
public class HibernateTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        SessionFactory sessionfactory = new Configuration().configure("Hibernate/hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionfactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(UserDetails.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("UserName","User5"));
        List<UserDetails> user =(List<UserDetails>) criteria.list();
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
        for(UserDetails u : user)
        {
            System.out.println("Name of User is : "+u);
        }
    }
}
```

**UserDetails:**

```
@Entity
public class UserDetails 
{
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO) 
    private int UserId;
    private String UserName;

    public int getUserId() {
        return UserId;
    }
    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        UserId = userId;
    }
    public String getUserName() {
        return UserName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        UserName = userName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Implement the toString() method

Answer (score 0):

You are currently trying to print the entire UserDetails object, but I think you are trying to print just the username...

```
System.out.println("Name of User is : " + u.getUserName());
```

Answer (score 0):

You should override the [toString method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()).

```
@Entity
public class UserDetails 
{
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO) 
    private int UserId;
    private String UserName;

    public int getUserId() {
        return UserId;
    }
    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        UserId = userId;
    }
    public String getUserName() {
        return UserName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        UserName = userName;
    }

    public String toString() {
      return getUserName() + " (id = " + getUserId().toString()  + ")"
}
```